# How can I search a list of text strings for more than one word or collection of words in Power Query?

Tags: list, powerquery

I have a table of data that I converted into a list using Table.ColumnsNames, and with this list I want to be able to select multiple items in the list and put into a new list and remove all items I did not select. For examples my current list contains {Apple, Pear, Orange, Banana} I want to extract "Apple" and "Banana" from the list and into a new one.

I tried doing this with List.contains or List.FindText but you can only select one parameter to such as "Apple" or "Banana" not both.

If anyone has a solution for this it would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

you want List.Intersect or List.Difference   See documentation at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-difference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-intersect

This looks for [Apple Pear Dog] from list of [Apple Pear Orange Banana] and returns [Apple Pear]

```
= List.Intersect ({{"Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Banana"},{"Apple", "Pear", "Dog"}})
```